# While updating a column using merge I am getting Error: ORA-38104

Tags: oracle, merge

I am trying to update BUNDLE_NAME from below table,
My Query is :

```
MERGE INTO SOURCE S USING 
(SELECT 'MANIFEST_ID' KEY,'CART' BUNDLE_NAME FROM DUAL) D
ON(S.KEY = D.KEY AND S.BUNDLE_NAME = D.BUNDLE_NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET BUNDLE_NAME = 'EPI';
```

but it gives me the following error:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "S"."BUNDLE_NAME"
>   38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
>   *Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause**

--My requirement is that I want to update using merge statement only--

Comment: Are you really only using those fixed values, or is this just a demo? If it is that simple, why do you want to use a merge rather than an update?

Comment: No actually I just wanted to know the reason that why Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated

Comment: [Because those are the rules](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF55137) *8-) I imagine it's to keep a stable result set throughout the evaluation of all the clauses (and in parallel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `bundle_id` in the `on` clause if you're trying to update it. As it's a fixed value, you can have it in a `where` clause instead:

```
MERGE INTO SOURCE S
USING (SELECT 'MANIFEST_ID' KEY FROM DUAL) D
ON (S.KEY = D.KEY)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET BUNDLE_NAME = 'EPI'
WHERE S.BUNDLE_NAME = 'CART';
```

But you don't need a merge, you can do a simple update:

```
UPDATE SOURCE S
SET S.BUNDLE_NAME = 'EPI'
WHERE S.KEY = 'MANIFEST_ID'
AND S.BUNDLE_NAME = 'CART';
```

Comment: Regarding that `WHERE` clause, it's worth mentioning that it doesn't seem to profit from any indexes on `BUNDLE_NAME`, so the `UPDATE` statement (or [some other workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009328/521799)) definitely seems preferrable

Answer (score 1):

[There are a few possible workarounds which can be used to outsmart the parser](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/02/how-to-work-around-ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated/), at least until Oracle 18c. One of them is to wrap your predicate in a row value expression predicate using an additional dummy column:

```
MERGE INTO SOURCE S USING 
(SELECT 'MANIFEST_ID' KEY,'CART' BUNDLE_NAME FROM DUAL) D
ON(S.KEY = D.KEY AND (S.BUNDLE_NAME, 'dummy') = ((D.BUNDLE_NAME, 'dummy')))
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET BUNDLE_NAME = 'EPI';
```